# invalid use of incomplete type/ foward declaration of

Tags: c++, qt5

I've been looking for info about this problem .. but none of the solutions I've found have helped me, I really hope that you can helpme

- maintabholder.h:

  ```
  #ifndef MAINTABHOLDER_H
  #define MAINTABHOLDER_H

  #include <QMainWindow>

  namespace Ui {
  class MainTabHolder;
  }

  class MainTabHolder : public QMainWindow
  {
      Q_OBJECT

  public:
      explicit MainTabHolder(QWidget *parent = 0);
      ~MainTabHolder();

  private:
      Ui::MainTabHolder *ui;
  };
  #endif // MAINTABHOLDER_H
  ```
- maintabholder.cpp:

  ```
  #include "maintabholder.h"
  #include "ui_maintabholder.h"

  MainTabHolder::MainTabHolder(QWidget *parent) :
      QMainWindow(parent),
      ui(new Ui::MainTabHolder)
  {
      ui->setupUi(this);
  }

  MainTabHolder::~MainTabHolder()
  {
      delete ui;
  }
  ```
- main.cpp:

  ```
  #include "maintabholder.h"
  #include <QApplication>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QApplication a(argc, argv);
      MainTabHolder w;
      w.show();
      return a.exec();
  }
  ```
- ui_maintabholder.h
              #ifndef UI_MAINTABHOLDER_H
      #define UI_MAINTABHOLDER_H

  ```
  #include <QtCore/QVariant>
  #include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>
  #include <QtWidgets/QAction>
  #include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
  #include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
  #include <QtWidgets/QHBoxLayout>
  #include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
  #include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
  #include <QtWidgets/QSpacerItem>
  #include <QtWidgets/QTabWidget>
  #include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>
  #include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

  QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

  class Ui_Form
  {
  public:
      QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
      QTabWidget *tabWidget;
      QWidget *comicViewer;
      QWidget *comicSearcher;
      QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
      QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout_2;
      QPushButton *pushButton;
      QSpacerItem *horizontalSpacer;
      QPushButton *pushButton_2;
      QWebView *webView;

      void setupUi(QWidget *Form)
      {
          if (Form->objectName().isEmpty())
              Form->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("Form"));
          Form->resize(531, 308);
          horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(Form);
          horizontalLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("horizontalLayout"));
          tabWidget = new QTabWidget(Form);
          tabWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("tabWidget"));
                  comicViewer = new QWidget();
          comicViewer->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("comicViewer"));
          comicViewer->setCursor(QCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor));
          tabWidget->addTab(comicViewer, QString());
          comicSearcher = new QWidget();
          comicSearcher->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("comicSearcher"));
          verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout(comicSearcher);
          verticalLayout->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("verticalLayout"));
          horizontalLayout_2 = new QHBoxLayout();
          horizontalLayout_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("horizontalLayout_2"));
          pushButton = new QPushButton(comicSearcher);
          pushButton->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton"));

          horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(pushButton);

          horizontalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

          horizontalLayout_2->addItem(horizontalSpacer);

          pushButton_2 = new QPushButton(comicSearcher);
          pushButton_2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("pushButton_2"));
          pushButton_2->setEnabled(false);

          horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(pushButton_2);


          verticalLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayout_2);

          webView = new QWebView(comicSearcher);
          webView->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("webView"));
          webView->setUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("about:blank")));

          verticalLayout->addWidget(webView);

          tabWidget->addTab(comicSearcher, QString());

          horizontalLayout->addWidget(tabWidget);


          retranslateUi(Form);

          tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);


          QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(Form);
      } // setupUi

      void retranslateUi(QWidget *Form)
      {
          Form->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("Form", "Form", 0));
          tabWidget->setTabText(tabWidget->indexOf(comicViewer), QApplication::translate("Form", "Comic Viewer", 0));
          pushButton->setText(QApplication::translate("Form", "Go to SubManga", 0));
          pushButton_2->setText(QApplication::translate("Form", "Download Comic", 0));
          tabWidget->setTabText(tabWidget->indexOf(comicSearcher), QApplication::translate("Form", "Search For Comics", 0));
      } // retranslateUi

  };

  namespace Ui {
      class Form: public Ui_Form {};
  } // namespace Ui

  QT_END_NAMESPACE

  #endif // UI_MAINTABHOLDER_H
  ```

the compiler errors are:

```
    [...]\maintabholder.cpp: In constructor 'MainTabHolder::MainTabHolder(QWidget*)':
    [...]\maintabholder.cpp:6:16: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::MainTabHolder'
    In file included from [...]\maintabholder.cpp:1:0:
    [...]\maintabholder.h:7:7: error: forward declaration of 'class Ui::MainTabHolder'
    [...]\maintabholder.cpp:8:7: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::MainTabHolder'
    In file included from [...]\maintabholder.cpp:1:0:
    [...]\maintabholder.h:7:7: error: forward declaration of 'class Ui::MainTabHolder'
    [...]\maintabholder.cpp: In destructor 'virtual MainTabHolder::~MainTabHolder()':
    [...]\maintabholder.cpp:13:12: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator: [enabled by default]
    [...]\maintabholder.cpp:13:12: warning: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Ui::MainTabHolder' [enabled by default]
    In file included from [...]\maintabholder.cpp:1:0:
    [...]\maintabholder.h:7:7: warning: forward declaration of 'class Ui::MainTabHolder' [enabled by default]
    [...]\maintabholder.cpp:13:12: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined
```

Can you give a help with this? I would appreciate it...

Comment: Show us file `ui_maintabholder.h` and tell, what compile system (IDE, make util, etc.) do you use

Comment: At a guess, does `ui_maintabholder.h` use the same include guard as `maintabholder.h`?  The fact you use the class name as an include guard in one makes me suspicious about the header for an identically named class in a different namespace.

Comment: Couple of questions: Why are you enclosing `MainTabHolder` in namespace ? Why do you want an instance of it as the class member ? If you construct it the way you are doing in initializer list, it would result an infinite recursion ( if enclosing class in namespace is the one outside of the namespace ). If you want forward declaration, just `class MainTabHolder;` is sufficient.

Comment: @Mahesh This construction fully generated by Qt's wizard. I don't think, that it's a good idea to change generated code. `ui_maintabholder.h` should contain **another** class `MainTabHolder` in namespace `Ui`

Comment: @borisbn I amn't familiar with Qt. Just posted my doubts on looking the code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a file generated by `uic` from Qt; you should verify that this tool successfully generate the file, by for example checking the build output and the file itself. Also, check that it is in the `*.pro` file (ie, that `maintabholder.h` is marked to be processed by `uic`).

I personnally advise to use the [multiple inheritance method](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#the-multiple-inheritance-approach) for ui :

```
// in maintabholder.h
// ...
#include "ui_maintabholder.h"

class MainTabHolder : public QMainWindow, public Ui::MainTabHolder
{
    // ...
};
```

Simpler to use, and if you have a problem with the `ui_*.h` file the error is more explicit.

*You should post `ui_maintabholder.h`.*

Comment: hey thanks for opening my eyes!, well i guess the problem was that the ui file i was using, i made it for testing in other project and i just copied that file to this, the variable names are a lot different ... i will try to repair my mistakes.. im sorry for taking your time  ... im just a noob, by the way thanks a lot

Comment: No problem! If this answer helped you, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it. You can also upvote if you feel so :)

Answer (score 0):

You included the ui define head in your .cpp file, and defined a private member "Ui::MainTabHolder *ui;" in your .h file, so you need to add a forward declaration in your .h file(maintabholder.h:) before your class defination:

```
class Ui_MainTabHolder;
```

here Ui_MainTabHolder is your Ui class name, check your own project for correct one.